# Unable to activate rails 3.0.1 because of bundler version conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

so I run:

```
$ gem install rails --version 3.0.1

Successfully installed rails-3.0.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.1...
```

then I get the error:

```
$ rails -v
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate rails-3.0.1, because bundler-1.1.4 conflicts with bundler (~> 1.0.0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:746:in `activate'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1232:in `gem'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to update to bundler 1.1.4.

`gem update bundler`

should do the trick.

Comment: I have the same error as above. I ran this fix, but bundler is "upt to date" and when i try rails -v again I receive the same exact output as before. Help!

Comment: The issue here is not from bundler being out of date, but rather too up-to-date. `~> 1.0.0` means any version from `1.0.0` upto, but not including, `1.1.0`.

Comment: Colin is right, see his answer, mine should be unaccepted so i can remove it.

Answer (score 8):

So Rails 3.0.1 requires Bundler `v1.0.0` - `v1.0.22` (actually any `1.0.x` version up to, but not including, 1.1.0), but you have a newer version of Bundler that's being loaded when Rails is started. You could uninstall the newer version(s) of Bundler (though this is a crappy way to deal with the issue) or since you're using RVM, just create a gemset for Rails 3.0.1.

```
$ rvm gemset create rails_3.0.1
$ rvm gemset use rails_3.0.1
$ gem install rails -v 3.0.1
$ rails -v
3.0.1
```

*Note: this requires that Bundler not be in your `global` gemset for the Ruby version you're trying to use. If the `global` gemset contains a Bundler version equal to or higher than 1.1.0 then you'll get the same error as before.*

**Update:** A little explanation about `~>` and RubyGems versioning might be handy. The [section on pessimistic version constraint](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74) in the RubyGems docs does a fantastic job of covering everything.

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly due to Ruby v1.9.2/3 uses bundler v1.1.4 while Rails v3.0.1 requires bundler v~1.0.0. Hence, by simply updating the Rails version to v3.2.6, the conflict is solved. This conflict can be easily solved by matching the Ruby and Rails version.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with mysql. I uninstalled mysql gem and I installed the newest version of mysql gem. Is RVM ok?